# Merging all vector files within directory with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, merge

I am unsuccessfully trying to merge all shapefiles in a given directory using QGIS 2.18. I do not want to navigate to the folder using QGIS GUI tools. Instead, I want my script to include all shapefiles in a certain location.
For now, what I am getting, is a copy of one random file only. I suppose the semantics of my qgis:mergevecorlayers algorithm is not appropriate.

```
import glob, os, processing
path_to_shp = "C:/Temp/Tracks/"
os.chdir(path_to_shp)
for file in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    uri = path_to_shp + fname
    processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", uri, "C:/Temp/Tracks/merged.shp")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calling the processing.runalg() within the for-loop. That means for every file, it will run the algorithm with only that file. Modify your script to first create a list of files and supply that list to the algorithm

```
import glob, os, processing
path_to_shp = "C:/Temp/Tracks/"
os.chdir(path_to_shp)
filelist = []
for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    uri = path_to_shp + fname
    filelist.append(uri)

fileliststring = ';'.join(filelist)        
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", fileliststring, "C:/Temp/Tracks/merged.shp")
```

Note that this answer is for 2.18. In QGIS 3.x, you don't need to create a string with + characters between your file names. You can just supply the python list.

Comment: @ spatialthoughts - I'm running your solution in QGIS 3.6.1, passing 'filelist' directly to the processing algorithm in place of fileliststring. Getting the following error:

TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.checkParameterValues(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Do you have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The algorithm expects a string, not a list. That's why we take te list of files and create a coma-separated text from it before passing it to the algorithm

Comment: @ spatial thoughts, thanks for your reply, but doing so leads to the following error: TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.checkParameterValues(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'. I've set up a separate question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348508/merge-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory-pyqgis which contains code examples and more explanatory text. Would be grateful if you could have a look.