# Merge all shapefiles in a directory - PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to merge all shapefiles in a directory using the following Python script from the console in QGIS 3.4.

The script was sourced from the following question:

[Merging all vector files within directory with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327398/merging-all-vector-files-within-directory-with-qgis)

gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327398/merging-all-vector-files-within-directory-with-qgis

```
import glob, os, processing
path_to_shp = "P:/GIS/Basemapping/Topographic Area Schema 1/"
os.chdir(path_to_shp)
filelist = []
for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    uri = path_to_shp + fname
    filelist.append(uri)

fileliststring = ';'.join(filelist)
processing.run("qgis:mergevectorlayers", fileliststring, "P:/GIS/Basemapping/Topographic Area Schema 1/merged.shp")
```

Running this results in:

```
TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.checkParameterValues(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

The first time I ran into this I checked the input parameters for the algorithm using:

`processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")`

Based on the algorithmHelp I assumed I should be passing a list of filepaths as input:

```
list[str]: list of layer sources
```

Running the following modification of the original script:

```
import glob, os, processing
path_to_shp = "P:/GIS/Basemapping/Topographic Area Schema 1/"
os.chdir(path_to_shp)
filelist = []
for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    uri = path_to_shp + fname
    filelist.append(uri)

processing.run("qgis:mergevectorlayers", filelist, "P:/GIS/Basemapping/Topographic Area Schema 1/merged.shp")
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.checkParameterValues(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

I feel I must be missing something obvious here. I've tried passing a list and a string of filepaths but neither seems to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you call `processing.run`. You should check out the official [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console)

Basically, `processing.run` expects the algorithm identifier, and a dictionary containing the processing parameters. This should work:

```
processing.run(
    "qgis:mergevectorlayers",
    {
        "LAYERS": filelist,
        "OUTPUT": "P:/GIS/Basemapping/Topographic Area Schema 1/merged.shp",
    },
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this code, but I receive "Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS" error. The script is exactly the same (safe for directories of course). I use QGIS 3.12.3 - I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: How do you create your "filelist"? It must be a python list of str